# Spring Cloud Stream - How to calculate average of metrics' values

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-platform

question from a Spring Cloud Stream rookie w/ little Kafka streams knowledge.
I need to produce a stream of time-series regarding compute resources metrics.
I receive a stream of json messages containing metrics like cpu usage, memory usage and so on.
I'm stuck in understanding how to sum metrics' values and the number of processed values in order to calculate the average value on a time-window base (i.e. 300s).

Incoming messages are like this:

```
[
   {
      "value": 27,
      "unit": "%",
      "type": "gauge",
      "metric": "cpu_usage",
      "time":1519314305.896,
      "host":"vm01-partition01",
   }
]
```

I'd like to obtain a json message like the following:

```
[
   {
      "value": 32,
      "aggregation": "mean",
      "metric": "cpu_usage",
      "time":1519314305.896,    //timestamp of the first processed value
      "host":"vm01-partition01",
   }
]
```

Anybody can switch on the light for me?
Thanks

Comment: This is certainly possible to do using the kafka streams API. Spring Cloud Stream provides its own programming model to leverage on Kafka Streams to write stream processing applications. Here are some docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_apache_kafka_streams_binder
Here are some samples: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams

Comment: Actually I've read the docs but seems that are supported only functions like count(), sum(), min() and max().   Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try to write some code using Kafka streams API and Spring Cloud Stream? If you have some same code and not working, please post here and we can take a look.